# Log In and Out report system / get the username and user id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently  working on a log-in/out system. It is working, but I want to get the username and id of it. Only the time and date of log in storing on the database.

Code:

```
if($_POST) 
    {
        $host="localhost"; // Host name
        $username="root"; // Mysql username
        $password=""; // Mysql password
        $db_name="thesisdb"; // Database name
        $tbl_name="user_tb"; // Table name

        // Connect to server and select database.
        mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or
        die("cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

        // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
        $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
        $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
        $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
        $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

        $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and 
        password='$mypassword'";


        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result))
            {
            $row = mysql_num_rows($result);

                $_SESSION['myusername'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['mypassword'] = strtoupper($row['password']);


                            $query = "INSERT INTO time_tb SET ";
                            $query = $query."username='".$myusername."', ";

                            $query = $query."logintime='".$p_time."', ";
                            $query = $query."date='".$p_date."' ";


                ExecuteQuery($query);

header("location:view2.php");


            }



        else 
            {
                echo  "<script>alert('Invalid Username/ Password')</script>";


            }




    }
?>
```

My Form :

```
<html>
<body></body>
<form method="post" name ="login">


<input type="text" name="myusername" placeholder="Username">
<br><br>

<input type="password" name="mypassword" placeholder="Password">
<br><br>


<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>


</html>
```

Comment: Where you get username and id ?

Comment: I don't see where are you setting `$myusername` from `$_POST` data

Comment: stop using `mysql_*`, its deprecated now. use `mysqli_*` and `PDO`. Also  remove if condition and change  like:-   `while($row = mysql_num_rows($result)){$_SESSION['myusername'] = $row['username'];$_SESSION['mypassword'] = strtoupper($row['password']);$_SESSION['id'] = strtoupper($row['id']); ....// rest code`

Comment: from my table @Milan

Comment: @MichaelAngeloJopia use once my code. also add `session_start();` on top of your each `.php` page just after `<?php`, other wise you can not access `SESSION data`.

Comment: Still using MySQL ? please migrate to Mysqli or PDO !

Comment: Why are you saving passwords to session? That is a bad idea. If you don't have to save it to session, and it doesn't appear that you do actually need to, don't do it.

Comment: Also passwords should never, ever, ever be stored in plain text form, they should always be stored as hashes. PHP version 5.5 and newer has methods for dealing with password hashing. For PHP versions older then 5.5 there's a backwards compatible library available (sorry don't have the URL for it to hand)

Answer (score 0):

Your code relies on the ancient and deprecated feature of [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) that enabled the code to access the input variables without using the superglobal arrays, such as $_POST.

Fortunately, you cannot do that any longer, so you need to explicitly assign value $myusername and the other input variables:

```
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
```

You need to do this for all parameters received from the form.

Also, you miss session_start() from the beginning of the code. There is a function call to ExecuteQuery() , which is not declared anywhere. You also do not call mysql_fetch_assoc() to fetch the results of the select query. And as the commenters also pointed out, you should not use mysql_*() functions any longer. Used mysqli or pdo instead.

Answer (score 0):

The way you fetch the SQL result is wrong:

```
$row = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

The above code is to fetch the total number of rows being returned. So you cannot do this:

```
$row['username'] OR $row['password']
```

To fetch the column data do this instead:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$_SESSION['myusername'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = strtoupper($row['password']);
```

And finally your SQL insert statement should be like this instead:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO time_tb (id, username, logintime, date) ";
$query .= "VALUES({$row['id]}, {$row['username]}, {$p_time}, {$p_time})";
```

As further note, the [PHP MySQL Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) is already deprecated since PHP 5.5, use the [improved version](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

References:

- [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)
- [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
- [MySQL Insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)